# Aren't upvotes on comments supposed to increase rep?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, comments, upvotes

Please help me out here. Am I mistaken by thinking my rep used to change when someone upvoted my comment?

Am I just confusing it with something else or is it just an issue with my account?

If its an issue with my account then how to fix it?

If I'm the one who's just confused then would it not be a good thing to get rep points from upvoted comments, that may be helpful to either the person who asked the question or someone else who had a similar issue and got assisted by the comment?

Thank you.

Comment: You do get a badge for a fixed number of highly voted comment (Ten comments, each with a score of 5 or more - Pundit badge). Maybe you were thinking of that?

Answer (score 7):

> Am I mistaken by thinking my rep used to change when someone upvoted my comment?

Yes, you are mistaken.

> If I'm the one who's just confused then would it not be a good thing to get rep points from upvoted comments?

No, it would not be good. Comments have always been seen as ephemeral - things that can be removed at any time. If a comment has enough substance, it should be rolled into the post.

We do not want to make comments more prominent and induce massive comment threads. We are about questions and answers, not comments and commentary.

Comment: The thing is, sometimes a person's comment becomes an answer to question or gives you the right direction. Then doesn't that person deserve something good out of it?

Comment: @Dumisani, you can always award a bounty to one of their answers on other questions.

Comment: Arguably, then, they should have posted an answer, not a comment, @Dumisani.

Comment: You may find one line comments or comments that just give you a link to where you'll 'find the light'. Those are discouraged as being posted as answers. @Oded

Comment: @Dumisani - If someone will not put in the effort for a full answer, I don't see a reason to give them rep. Again - we don't need more comments. We need more good answers.

Comment: @Oded For readability at some point it might be good to update the answer. But not giving points for comments, unfortunately will be undermining teamwork and collaboration on solving issues fast. I often don't have time to fix all issues in a code but I see non-obvious reasons why this code could never work. If I publish this as an answer, I'd be getting downvotes because there are still other things that must be fixed. Giving points for early and helpful comments promote collaboration and teamwork. If you update the answer, you also get points, so both things can complement each other.

Comment: You are mistaking the reasons for having comments. Comments are *supposed* to be short lived. They are not supposed to be long lived or important. Giving reputation for them will emphasise them well beyond what we want. Our sites are about questions and answers, not about discussions.

Comment: @Oded Comments have two rationales: an addendum (something you think needs to be added (but is quite answer specific and doesn't warrant its own answer), but the author doesn't include - these must persist), or a discussion (which isn't supposed to be long lived). But as the engine is not able to differ between them, yep, giving rep is not great here.