# Why are we supposed to let incorrect answers stick around?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, wrong-answers

There has been a lot of noise recently about bad answers and people incorrectly flagging them for removal and a wave of responses saying "use your downvotes, idiot.  Flags aren't for *wrong* answers!".  And then they link back to [Shog9's canonical piece](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

I'm just confused why removing an answer is wrong?  The Stack Overflow Tour page says

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Okay that's great, but I don't really think that's supposed to mean a library full of wrong answers.  So yes, it's great that I have downvotes and can use them to push answers I think are 'bad' to the bottom, but still...they're there, being wrong, potentially confusing the next person to have the question and detracting from valid answers.

Do answers eventually disappear off the site if they're negative<sup>1</sup>?  What is the value of keeping things that the community has decided are wrong/bad/valueless?

<sup>1</sup> I guess I couldn't know if they did (because, y'know, disappearing), but I've seen plenty of negative answers so they definitely don't disappear immediately upon going negative.

Comment: Voting is a better way to determine technical accuracy than whichever mod/reviewers happen to see the flag.  Voting also encourages corrections/improvements via editing, whereas deletion encourages giving up.  (That said, very-high-rep users _can_ vote to delete negatively-scored answers.)

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote since I disagree, but tempted to upvote because (1) this is actually a good question and (2) the more upvotes this gets, the more people will see the two excellent answers posted so far. So...upvote it is!

Comment: On one occasion, I have deliberately left my negatively-scored, incorrect answer on a site because I know it serves to let readers know what *not* to do and is therefore actually helpful.

Comment: @Kyle judge question on its usefulness. **It isn't a feature request where voting means disagreement.** I see no feature requested here. Just a good question with OP's thoughts.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was under the impression (based on prior experience) that downvoting can be used to express disagreement in any discussion questions.

Comment: @KyleStrand: It is [documented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250876/245360). Well, just added it now ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's a question about voting on the non-meta site; there are already discussions elsewhere about when/why to vote on meta.

Comment: @Kevin what you think is helpful is probably actually really confusing to readers.  There is no reason I can think of to leave a known bad answer on a page.

Comment: I've met a lot wrong answers voted up to the top because they either only covered the most common case of the problem or got outdated or, and that's weird, nobody actually tried them for some reason (possibly, the OP found other solution and therefore didn't need to check).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Having done some searching: it's documented in the help center, which I (correctly) remembered as saying that *all* meta questions allow downvotes for disagreement; however, [there was a wording change that I didn't notice before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191880/218334), and as you state, **downvoting for disagreement is now limited to feature-requests only.**

Comment: @KyleStrand: Thanks for taking the time and effort to find this.

Comment: @KyleStrand In any case, may I ask what you disagree with?

Comment: Just because something is wrong, doesn't make it useless. If nothing else - to make clear to the next person thinking 'I wonder if...' that it is, in fact, not the right answer.

Comment: @Sobrique What if it's not clear to a (new) user that the negative number next to the (potentially) first answer means that it could well be the wrong answer?

Comment: I think that would have to fall under caveat emptor. If the code isn't out right harmful (in which case I think it _should_ be deleted) then they'll try it and find it doesn't work (and downvote too maybe). And if they put it into prod without testing, then there's really no help for them.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283456/1157054

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You're touching on a few different topics here...

#### Voting...

...is the primary method by which we extract a *collective opinion* from the readers of a post. **You** may think a given answer is wrong - or simply *not useful* in the context where it's written - but someone else may know something you don't and find it useful. If each reader votes on the answer, then the combined votes produce a...

#### ...Post Score...

...that reflects the combined evaluations of all voting readers. The theory is that (for reasonably objective, practical topics at least) this score eventually indicates which answers are accurate and useful - and which ones are not. Note that it does not specifically call out *incorrect information*, however the presence of wrong information can and frequently does motivate...

#### ...Rebuttals in comments and other answers...

...which serve to directly highlight bad advice and contrast it with good advice. This can be amazingly valuable. When I'm researching a problem and find contradictory advice scattered across the 'Net, I often find myself wondering why I should adopt one technique over another, particularly when the latter is more appealing: do I really *need* this flag, that error-checking, this complicated API? *Why do I have to use mysqli_ functions when I have a perfectly good example here for mysql_()?* You get the idea. Sometimes it's not enough to know what folks think the *right* answer is - you also need to **understand which alternatives are wrong!**

Which leads us to...

#### Deletion...

...serves multiple functions here. Anyone can delete their own post (with some minor restrictions), but when it comes to deleting *other people's* work the bar is pretty high: generally, the post should be completely useless *or **actively harmful** in some way* to be removed.

Every negatively-**scored** answer (remember, these are those where the *consensus of voters* is "useless") is *eligible* for deletion [by trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), but rarely are these actually removed unless they amount to noise, abuse, or serve to mislead readers in a way that can't easily be mitigated in some other fashion.

The default sort order for answers puts the highest-voted answers at the top, and the assumption is that folks who *need* an answer will usually read at least a few of them, starting from the top-ranked and working down until their needs are met. This mitigates much of the danger of keeping wrong answers around, while still allowing them to benefit in the cases mentioned above.

Which just leaves us with...

#### Flags...

...are exceptions, a way to break out of the normal lifecycle for posts on the site. A flag notifies either moderators or groups of users that a post may need special handling as it represents an urgent problem in one of three rough categories:

1. **Noise** (Very Low Quality / Not An Answer)
2. **Abuse** (Offensive / Spam)
3. **Something *really* unusual** (Other)

Remember, these are exceptions - you're saying the system will *break* if the post you're flagging isn't handled specially. As described above, *wrong* answers don't generally meet this criteria - the system was **designed** to handle them. What it doesn't handle might be described simply as [not even wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) - things that **aren't answers at all**, or are constructed (intentionally or otherwise) so confusingly as to make a fair evaluation by voters impossible or unlikely.

If you keep this in mind when flagging - and voting, and answering - you'll be helping to achieve the goal you quoted.

Comment: I would add to the "Flags..." section the ones dangeriously wrong. Things that could damage your system by deleting a bunch of files, causing a DDoS, etc.

Comment: How should one handle the "not an answer to ***this*** question?" type answers?  It is not unheard of to questions of "Why should I do X" and have an answer that is of the form "To do X, follow steps A, B, C".  It's an answer, kind of... but it doesn't answer this question (it might be an answer to a .  In the past, these have been hit or miss to raise a flag about.  Does it fall into the "not even wrong" region of necessary deletion (via flag or other - if so, how?), or is this something that should remain as an answer?

Comment: I think the model of SO works well if the question gets sufficient people with expertise to verify the correctness. However, it's not always the case, and wrong answers can rise to the top when it lacks verification and the voters just vote when the answer simply looks amazing. On large scale, I believe it belongs to "actively harmful" criteria for deletion, but on smaller scale, nothing can really be done to reduce visibility to the answer.

Comment: I've been told that an answer to *anything* is still an answer, which I find silly (if someone asks how to reverse a string in Python, and I give them how to calculate pi in cobol, that's still technically an "answer"), but whatever.

Comment: @Braiam misleading answer on chemistry boards led, though remotely, in an explosion in my kitchen. So much for the system handling wrong questions - it only handles them until they eliminate anybody who finds out they're wrong.

Comment: @Braiam - The key problem with that: how do we trust the flagger that this is actually harmful? For example, this answer was flagged to be deleted as being "harmful": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php/8529687#8529687 . Should we have taken the flagger at their word and deleted that? Questions of something being harmful or a poor practice requires subject matter expertise, which moderators cannot have for all possible areas of the site. Should moderators recognize and remove all answers that could be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: @BradLarson just use common sense! You just need to ask around. If you don't have the knownledge to determine something is harmful, you have *an army of users* that you can ask and confirm... heck, I bet that something like that would be mentioned somewhere too (btw, I don't see how it's harmful, but anything in php is potentially harmful, so...)

Comment: Comments are ephemeral are they not? A tool for clarifying questions, improving answers. Answers are supposed to be self-contained, are they not? Although sometimes difficult to keep rebuttal out, rebuttal "degrades" an answer when someone does change/delete the point being rebutted. Still not sure how this description, `With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming` fits what you have outlined. Are all the answers to a question to be taken together as "an answer in the library"? Or should we say, "answers, good or bad"?

Comment: You're describing "voting", @Braiam...

Comment: Don't confuse the process with the goal, @BillWoodger - the presence of scaffolding and dumpsters doesn't preclude the emergence of a solid structure, and may well enable just that.

Comment: I don't think there's a concrete answer to this, @MichaelT - *sometimes*, the asker just asked the wrong question. I talked about this a bit [over yonder](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag/286366#286366).

Comment: Sure. I think  didn't explain well.  I find them really useful and use them a lot. Ideally, by the time someone is researching something, the comments are no longer there because everything is in the answer. Or so I thought. Comments left around because an answerer has gone AWOL, or doesn't concur in some way are leaving the scaffolding etc lying around. It happens, but is not ideal. Part in the answer, part in the comments. Nothing in the answer, indicated in the comments. Good answer, nothing in the comments but it doesn't "look" like nothing, so can't be flagged.

Comment: @Shog9 is the threshold on Stack Overflow for an acceptable (as in "should remain as an answer") answer something that fundamentally answers the question? or something that addresses the question? (I have [written about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277048/289086) but have yet to have any substantial light shed on it... and now I tend to avoid flags that go to the moderators unless it is ***very*** clear cut as to what the action should be - and while I realize the mods like clear cut ones, declining all the hard judgement calls likely isn't the best answer either).

Comment: "The default sort order for answers puts the highest-voted answers at the top"... unless the crappy negatively-scored answer was accepted of course

Comment: No, I don't believe so. I was describing something actively harmful not only to the prestige of SO, but to the users/internet themself. Voting cannot fix stupidity, and I've seen several times people using the answer with several downvotes, that latter on comes barking to us about how much damage it caused.

Comment: You can't fix stupid, and I don't think it's Stack Overflow's remit to try. When a bunch of people have said 'bad idea' and you do it anyway, then ... well, perhaps using sites on the internet for code snippets is just not something you should be doing in the first place. Probably better that they get the problem earlier.

Comment: This answer is the sort of thing we need in the Help section - i.e. "Advanced site usage" area.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  ...not only that. We only know that default sort order works for googlers (who only _view_ content). We don't really know if it's the same for those who _rate_ content, [how many votes and flags are cast by users preferring active answer order](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250527/165773 "request for stats on this"). And if it's the case that garbage stands in the way of those who rate content for googlers, then I guess whole approach that sort by voting fixes everything is somewhat flawed

Answer (score 70):

Using flags to get moderators to delete incorrect answers is problematic for several reasons. First, it requires moderators to be subject matter experts in the field to make a judgment like that. We can't possibly have enough moderators to cover every technology on this site.

Blindly trusting flaggers would be a terrible idea, based on the number of flags people falsely cast on competing answers in an attempt to fool us into destroying them. Lots of people abuse flags to attack anything they disagree with, or to try to benefit themselves. This is why we can be more skeptical about some of these.

Beyond that, do you really want to have a small cabal of people decide what's correct and what's not? I certainly don't, and would much rather let the community judge correctness via votes.

Bad answers can also serve an educational purpose. If someone suggests a potential solution, and it becomes highly downvoted, that can indicate a way that you shouldn't do something. Comments and discussion around these bad answers can help people learn why certain practices are vulnerable, slow, etc. I know I've learned useful lessons from comments on downvoted answers.

Comment: I'm surprised both answers here have an equal number of upvotes, given that Shog9's is long enough that I'd expect most people not to bother reading this one after reading it. That said, I'm glad people seem to be sticking around for yours, especially given the "small cabal" sentence.

Comment: I will say that, while full of useful and true information, most of this answer doesn't address the question, which is "*Why* keep answers that the community thinks are bad".  The only pieces of the answer that touch on that are in the last paragraph.  The question presupposed that the voting system works to define "good" and "bad".  That said, the tooltip says "This answer is useful", not "This answer is best"...that's why we have the checkmark.

Comment: @ABMagil: Actually, that's not why we have the checkmark. That's just for the asker to mark which answer he appreciated most. For example because it best fit his preconceptions, it's the code he can copy-and-paste without thinking (and thus is nigh useless to everyone else, and probably even to OP if he only knew), it did not bother him with any warnings, and maybe it showed him the fastest way to hell and damnation. Of course, many askers actually try to mark the best and most educative answer, not the one which lets him leave fastest.

Answer (score 7):

My point of view:

**The point of building "a library of detailed answers"** (as opposed to, say, a carefully curated FAQ page where there is only one answer for any question) is that usually *"There is more than one way to do it"* and StackOverflow wants to educate about all of them. (This is a key point: SO is about *education, not information*.)

**The point of voting** is to mark some of these answers as very useful, some as somewhat useful, and some as not useful/misleading/problematic/wrong.

**The point of keeping answers with negative scores**, then, is that the comprehensive education must include everything that somebody once thought might be a good idea, even if it is not. Not only because somebody else might think so again, but also because finding out (or reading, in a comment) why a wrong answer is wrong can be a useful intellectual exercise.

**The bottom line:** Removing wrong answers, once they have proper negative score, would reduce the value of StackOverflow, not increase it.

**Oh, and yes:** This is an argument for *not removing all* answers with negative scores. It is not an argument for *keeping all* of them; some will be bad enough to not be protected by the above value proposition. (Thanks, l4mpi)

Comment: Badges here are designed to encourage desired behaviour. If everything everyone has ever thought about and posted as an answer is supposed to stay, what is the reasoning for the Peer Pressure and Disciplined badges, both of which reward deleting answers?

Comment: "comprehensive education must include everything that somebody once thought might be a good idea, even if it is not." - this assumes the answers contain anything of value and are more than random brain farts. See e.g. [this useless answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28849393/1110381) (VLQ disputed) - it's completely worthless as it simply has nothing to do with OPs problem. You could copypaste this answer to any random python question and it would have just as much value (except if you by chance hit a question where OP wants to split strings). Doesn't have any educational value IMO.

Answer (score 6):

I'd love some way to get wrong answers deleted. Why? Downvoting doesn't work. Where? Niche tags.

Here's an example. It's from a tag with 28 questions.

[Need the last entry while using XSUM in SYNCSORT JCL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18400186/1927206)

There are three answers: one with three ways to achieve exactly what is wanted with the amount of code that is needed for each (zero votes); one which may have been a reasonable suggestion 25 years ago, which is to write an exit program (one vote, since he finally included a caveat after a long exchange of comments); one with a single solution including two passes of the data and two SORTs of the data in two steps (three votes).

The latter solution was posted first, and picked up the votes from people visiting the tag. 2800 visitors now think that's the best way to do it, and that the idiotic solution is the second-best way to do it.

On the Mainframe, clients pay for processing. The source of two poor solutions which cost clients money for running or for coding (and then running). The source of the solutions - Stackoverflow.

Here's another example from the same tag:

[How to get the records count using Syncsort?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8515600/1927206)

This question has the first answer I ever flagged. When I discovered that NAA is not for things that plain don't work, and a poor way to do it even if they were to work.

Two answer, both with a score of one before I saw them. One from a guy who works for the company who write the product, one, two days later, from someone who was trying to help, to be fair, but who made a terrible job of it. Both were sitting there with the same score.

Why don't *I* downvote answers in niche tags? Because it has not effect. One downvote, one, two or three upvotes. No-one is ever going to self-delete that.

So, Stackoverflow has crap answers in niche tags, and no real way to address it. As has been pointed out, even a custom flag would rely on niche knowledge by a flag-handler, and that is unrealistic to expect.

We can live with it. We have no choice. There is nothing we can do. It's only a niche, after all.

(OK, that's not the only reason I don't downvote answers. In the slightly more popular other niche tags I participate in, we have people supplying answers who are very willing to correct things pointed out in comments. There, when there is a downvote, we can tell it is a *stain* that comes from outside :-) )

Comment: Noone downvotes, meaning downvoting does not work, thus you don't downvote, meaning noone downvotes. If that ain't a vicious circle...

Comment: @Deduplicator No. This is a different tag. Tiny. Lucky to get any type of a vote at all. In the other tags I mention, things are sorted out in comments. Answer downvotes are just not needed, and we don't get left with crap answer hanging around.

Comment: @Deduplicator Just to clarify the other part of the No. Where I have downvoted answers, nothing happens. +1/-1. No-one deletes because they are +8 on the trade. Chance of getting six downvotes an a niche answer is minimal. Have a look at some of the questions. *10 views a week* is often  optimistic. Once it gets to 40 views after two days, you know that's about it.

Comment: You don't need to get it deleted to convey that it is bad - downvoting and commenting achieve a lot of this on their own. If you do those things and there's still evidence that people are being misled, then there's a discussion to be had.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Comments are ephemeral. There should be no comments which are required to understand an answer. They are a tool for immediate communication on question and answer, not a long-term adjunct to anything. If a searcher finds an answer with a score of two and another with zero, the score of two looks better even though they can't see the +3/-1. Even if they could see a downvote, two still looks better than zero. In niche or low-traffic tags, there are just not enough people attending to make downvotes noticeable. So, no. Niche, low-traffic, doesn't work.

Comment: In practice a comment containing a reasonable criticism of a low-traffic answer that isn't addressed by a subsequent edit to the question is likely to stick around. Anyway, why not at least do those things? It would certainly be better than nothing.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam 1,027 Comments says my Profile. Many, many more comments have been deleted in cooperation with people amending their questions/answers, to keep things tidy. All my (proved) useless downvotes I recovered during an attempt, eventually successful, to reach 3000 (things are very slow in low-traffic tags).  So, been there, done that. Comments are ephemeral, it is formally stated somewhere. An answer should stand (or fall) without its comments. Not true in practice, and no evidence that searchers-of-a-quick-fix even *read* the comments.

Comment: If you downvote and comment and people still don't read that, that sounds like their loss. Even if deletion was appropriate, if you can't even get enough users to downvote to say -3 in the tag, how would you get enough to delete?

Comment: With the criticism that you're capable of extending to these answers, it seems like you have a better idea of what a good solution is. If that is the case, why don't you answer them?

Comment: @CarrieKendall From my answer: `We can live with it. We have no choice. There is nothing we can do. It's only a niche, after all`. What works for the popular tags, doesn't scale down to the niche tags. That applies to everything, not just what is being discussed here. Attempts to address that in any way would probably lead to a proliferation of "new" niche tags to reap benefits. Niche can't be prioritised without it being abused. Perhaps if there were duly "authorised" niche tags, but there'd still be proliferation. Niches are "unfair", but I don't know how that could be changed.

Comment: @CarrieKendall The point of my answer was to be a minority opinion vs the two main answers. Delicately treading to not appear too "ranty" :-) I contribute in niche tags. Much of many things is way, way, way out of reach for niche tags. In my largest niche, it'll take me six years to be the first gold tag-badge. Closing close-bait doesn't happen fast enough, so they get answered. Comments on those. Downvotes? Why? No chance to lead to self-delete as soon as there is one upvote.

Comment: That behavior happens in all tags. Fastest guns gonna shoot, regardless of how _niche_ the tag is. My point is, if you're able to deduce what is _good_ and _bad_ then a valid way to combat misinformation is to provide **better answers**

Comment: @CarrieKendall which sits at zero, contrasted to three and one. If you come searching for a quick fix, which you gonna chose? Studiously refer to the comments... balance the answers in themselves ignoring the votes? Remember, the casual non-user searcher often won't even be aware of downvotes (need enough rep to see the breakdown of +/-). Yes, the thing happens in non-niche tags, but the better answers attract votes :-). Niche tags *do not operate like mainstream tags*. When the same thing happens, FGITW, the *outcome* is not the same. All is different :-)

Comment: @CarrieKendall Where have I given the impression that I don't contribute an answer? If you point that out, I'll correct it. Look at the tag (syncsort) for the two linked questions. I created the tag. And the DFSORT tag. On old questions, I provide answers when my answers are better than what is already there. If there is nothing to add to existing answers, I don't answer... Dealing with crap answers other than that is the issue. An unseen and out-of-weight downvote does nothing. Comments, sure, but they have a built-in gun-to-the-head. I've had more than the occasional comment moderated out...

Comment: @CarrieKendall That's an interesting set of answers. It looks to me like TechDo was first with a correct solution, languishes at the bottom of the votes. Question is "I've previously worn shoes, now I've got boots. How do I attach them so they don't fall off my feet". The *only* explanation of why ALTER is inappropriate is in the... comments. 200k views, 146 upvotes for an answer which wasn't accurate for the first six months :-) As to a non-SQL answer, I think it is useful, as searchers wanting to do that may come up with that question. 23 votes for pull-down/select is impressive :-)

Answer (score 4):

> What is the value of keeping things that the community has decided are wrong/bad/valueless?

To *convey* that this is bad, perhaps? How else would be deter some other well meaning ignoramus from posting the same answer all over again? (I have seen that happen even now due to self-censorship, and it was annoying to point out the same mistake over and over again ...)

Comment: There's a badge to encourage the removal of downvoted posts. So removing downvoted posts is the encouraged outcome. Isn't this what downvotes are for? Maybe not, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

It's because **wrong answers provide contrast and contrast builds understanding**.  This doesn't just apply to answers on SO, this applies to learning in general.  Not only that but these answers also attract comments from people explaining why the answer is wrong, but I'll get to that in a bit.

The best example I can think of to illustrate the idea that contrast builds understanding would be design patterns.  From the `design-pattern` tag wiki:

> In software engineering, a design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design.

Probably the hardest aspect of learning design patterns is figuring out *when* to use them.  If you don't properly understand the motivation for using a specific pattern, it's easy to see it as a shiny new toy that should be used at every opportunity.

The motivation for using design patterns becomes a lot clearer when you've spent a good amount of time working with poorly designed code.  You can see for yourself the types of problems the patterns are trying to solve and help you avoid.  Without having the experience of working with bad code, it's easy for the motivation to become some kind of holy gospel that you follow to the letter and nothing more; it becomes little more than, "it's good practice."

Seeing the bad side of something is what allows you to ultimately appreciate the good side of it.  If you only keep around the good advice, you're not telling both sides of the story.

That said, bad advice should always be tempered and this is why I believe it's of the utmost importance for downvoters to leave comments as to why they feel something is wrong.  It's important to do that because **comments accurately portray your opinion** whereas a downvote doesn't.  (How many times have you seen someone ask, "Why the downvote?")  Just doing that would go a long way to improving the problem with niche tags.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287603/why-are-we-supposed-to-let-incorrect-answers-stick-around?cb=1#comment163527_287737 plus comments are ephemeral, and things are supposed to finally stand without comments (I thought). The problem with niche tags is the number of people attending. How do you overturn three upvotes on a poor solution when someone can get on the All Time list for the tag with one answer scoring two (they'd be all-time equal sixth, for instance).

Comment: @BillWoodger I don't see how comments are any more, or less, ephemeral than the answer they're qualifying, unless of course the answer is edited.  However, surely (at least, I'd hope) that's a positive action as a result of taking on board the criticism from a comment with a view to improving the quality of the answer.

Comment: @BillWoodger Also, with regards to the badges, let me give you an example.  I flagged a guy who was posting really, really bad answers to questions and linking to his blog at the end of each one.  He received downvotes for each answer, but no-one had left a comment explaining the problem.  Those answers weren't just low quality, they were, of course, spam.  Those answers were worthy of being deleted, whether by the user himself or, as in this case, by a moderator after I flagged.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure Peer Pressure is designed to reward spammers deleting their own stuff :-) Try this for the expected meaning and worth of comments: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254805/1927206

Comment: @BillWoodger I see where you're coming from.  I find this quote interesting though: `We do not want to make comments more prominent and induce massive comment threads.`  For the most part, I agree with that.  High-quality answers tend to convey all of the information they need, so they naturally reduce the number of comments they could otherwise attract.  Incorrect answers, however, tend to be the opposite, but I don't see that as a bad thing.  Leaving a comment on a bad answer provides the opportunity for the answerer to improve their answer.

Comment: @BillWoodger With regards to the comments themselves, I wouldn't delete a comment I posted to an answer I felt was wrong unless the answerer provided an edit that addressed whatever issue(s) I had posted about.  For anyone that takes this site seriously, I can't imagine why they would take the trouble to post that sort of comment only to delete it later.  I just don't see how that can be an issue.

Comment: And also the line before that: `If a comment has enough substance, it should be rolled into the post.` I don't think that that is current community-accepted behaviour... yes, I leave my comments unless they are addressed, then I (try to keep up with it and) remove them.

Comment: @BillWoodger I agree with that, but I'm not sure I would agree that it's not community-accepted behaviour - I genuinely think it is.  The real problem is that there an awful lot of very technical answers given here, so people have to be very careful when editing someone else's answer.  It could just be that people are reluctant to do so.  Regarding the removal of comments, if you've kept up with it, and you're willing to remove them, doesn't that then indicate that your issue with the answer has been resolved?

Comment: I've never seen a comment which has the content "this is a bad answer" rolled into the answer as the OP of that answer has just abandoned it. By a <2000-rep user I'd expect that to get the edit rejected without a second thought. Having been schooled on the way up how to do it, and without seeing it done, it would seem to me rank-breaking to go ahead and do it now :-) Sure, comments are very effective where they are effective. They are not effective where they are not. Where errors have been corrected, there is no need to highlight that there were errors originally. Where not corrected...

Comment: @BillWoodger Ah, so what you're _really_ talking about then is comment _redundancy_, in which case I agree there is no system currently in place that deals with that.  That's entirely down to users following up their own comments.  I'd suggest a system that notifies us when an answer, or question, we've commented on is modified, but I think any users with a lot of reputation would quickly want to burn my house down if that was implemented. ;-)

Comment: It is more not-really-redundant-though-expected-to-be. The comment is vital to someone wasting time on the answer but it could also disappear at any moment. To make it permanent, and part of the answer, I've just never seen done. I do flag comments for removal, where they suit the flags, but I try not to go wild with it as someone has to then do the work.