# Editing and downvoting an answer

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes

Having earned my first tiny review privileges, I recently came across a late answer by a new user that had the code indented wrong and partially not at all. So I [fixed it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28913799/revisions) but then I looked at the answer and the question more closely and I'm convinced the code actually does not do what it's supposed to, so I downvoted.

Was this the right thing to do? Should I have left the formatting as it was and only downvote since the answer is wrong in my opinion? Should I maybe even have flagged it?

Comment: Your general guide should always be - "does this help future users of the site?"  In many ways, getting a question answered is a useful side effect - the true purpose is as a reference for future users. By that yard stick: Edit to improve clarity. Downvote to indicate wrongness. (Although I'd suggest double checking you weren't responsible for introducing the wrongness :))

Comment: You could have add a comment and document you concerns. Maybe the answer will be corrected by the original author. And it could be helpful to future readers who might wonder why it does not work. If everything is all right, someone else usually comment that, too.

Comment: I do that all the time with questions.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with cleaning up the post to your best ability, and afterwards come to the conclusion that the post is still *not useful*.

Just vote according to the merit of the post.
And kudos for trying to raise its worth beforehand.

As to flagging, that's not for wrong answers, only for mis-placed posts, non-answers, complete garbage and other exceptional situations.

Also, there is one exception to editing to clarify always being good:
Do not edit SPAM / offensive posts. Just flag and be done.

Comment: I'll often apply a formatting tool to code that's a mess before even bothering to figure out what it does. As long as it's syntactically valid, I'll edit  to replace, and then decide if it's wrong. (but double check that I've not introduced the error :))

Comment: "mis-placed posts" some mods disagree, esp for comment-answers

Answer (score 34):

You did the right thing.

Editing at the very least teaches the author of that answer how to correctly format a post. You are keeping the site clean and are helping to raise the standard.

If you then found that the answer is unhelpful you were right in down-voting it. The answer only contains a code dump with no explanation, and if the code is not even the right solution, that's all the more wrong.

You'd never flag wrong answers, however. See [Why are we supposed to let incorrect answers stick around?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287603/why-are-we-supposed-to-let-incorrect-answers-stick-around), but basically wrong answers play a role too, showing how *not* to do something.