# As a new user, should I bother suggesting edits to fairly obvious duplicates?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Evidently I am extremely new to Stack Overflow, and while trying to familiarize myself with how everything works I have been left with a burning question. If I find a question that is almost certainly a duplicate and has extremely poor formatting which greatly harms readability *(i.e. code is completely not formatted, multitude of confusing spelling mistakes, etc.)* in addition to flagging it as a duplicate, **is it worthwhile or wasting others' time** if I suggest an edit to fix severe question issues?

- On one hand, I have no doubt that were my edit to be approved for one of these questions, it would be easier for others to understand and consequently flag it (or vote to close it) as a duplicate as well, which could reduce the time necessary for it to be closed. Additionally, sometimes when looking up questions previous to having my own account on Stack Overflow, I found that duplicates appeared at the top of Google and I only found the canonical question by following through the duplicate. This makes me think that I should in fact suggest an edit, as other users may come across it while seeking the original question
- Contrarily however, editing would place my question in the Edit queue and then require 3 reviewers to approve it, which I have a nagging suspicion could be seen as a huge waste of time for reviewers when they see that I flagged the question as a duplicate anyways, which (*I think*) implies that I want users to be pointed towards the original canonical question anyways.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not really sure if this is a duplicate of that question, because it addresses off-topic or poor questions conceptually, and not really duplicate questions in particular?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the two questions are asking from different vantage points as well. Never mind.

Comment: Does this non-dupe help? [Editing an answer and then deciding to downvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287614/editing-and-downvoting-an-answer) Just remember that a question can be useful even if it's a duplicate, though that depends on how easy it is to find the master.

Comment: @Deduplicator Fitting username, and it does! So you're suggesting, so long as it is not entirely not-useful / spam / offensive, it's worth editing?

Comment: Yes, if the post is better after your edit (which implies it is not trash), editing is good. Just make the edit as comprehensive as reasonable, and there's no need to worry about the review-queue at all. That implies [removing signatures, taglines, greetings](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), correcting categorization (tags), proper formatting and all the other easy ones.

Comment: The only edit I really bothered with before hitting 2K was code formatting - because that significantly enhances readability, to the point where... well, it's basically illegible otherwise. Minor edits I didn't bother with though.

Comment: I disagree that removing greetings, signatures, etc. is worth going through the review queue. Try to limit formatting changes to ones on the significant side. Removing/replacing *wrong* tags is always good and important and worthwhile, but hesitate to go through review just to *add* tags, unless the post is missing a language tag that it clearly should have.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The first thing to consider is: **can it become a good question?**  As a duplicate this has a special meaning.  It means that the question can be written in a clear way that someone will find the question and go on to its duplicate.

If the post is one of a bajillion "its another null pointer exception" questions, this is a fairly high bar.  As I write this, there are [1420 linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/218384?lq=1) to the Java NPE question. Can you make the sign post to the question a good one?  One that people will find (because somehow they missed all the other thousand or so pointers to it)?

If no, it's probably ok to let it stand so that either it doesn't annoy someone in the queue (this isn't the best reason to not submit an edit) and that it can quietly go away.

If, on the other hand, it's an obvious duplicate to something that doesn't have as many duplicates and you can make it a good sign post, do so.

There's another factor in there too.  People who have edits to their posts are more likely to become longer term users than drive by questions. Showing someone how to write a good question is a good thing.  But if you can't write it as a good question, it's still going to get deleted some day.

So, if you are going to edit a question that is an obvious duplicate:

- Make sure it can be a good question
- Make sure that it is a good sign post
- Make sufficient edits on it (not just removing thanks) so that it improves the quality of the question.  Fix *everything*

Comment: The best reason, to my mind, to not edit the thousandth poorly asked version of a question is to allow it to be cleaned up post haste. You're wasting your own time polishing it, of course, but you're also going to make people think twice when they review it, when really they should not hesitate in relegating it to the bit bucket.