# Why can't you downvote your own answer?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I answered a question and it got up-voted.  I shortly realized that there was a problem in my code, so based on a meta QA I found this morning, I decided my best course would be to leave my previous answer and add a new, corrected one.  I also thought this would be more appropriate for 2 reasons:

1. Maybe the up-voter wouldn't have done so for the changed answer
2. I figured I would also go ahead and down-vote my previous answer as I believe it deserved

Imagine my surprise when trying to down-vote my own answer to get the alert to the effect that you cannot vote on your own posts.  Surely I understand why up-voting your own posts should not be allowed, but why not down-voting?

Comment: Voting is for *others* to indicate the quality of your posts. You yourself can edit the post instead, or delete it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to allow you to downvote your own answer - if you don't think it's good, why would you leave it like that?

Comment: Why would I do that?  I already know my answers are rubbish :)

Answer (score 27):

If your know that your own answer is not useful you should either:

- Fix it so that it is actually useful, instead of being not useful.
- Delete it.

Leaving around content that you know isn't useful, even if you indicate that you think it's not useful, isn't productive.

Comment: And yet, [according to the Meta thread that George Jempty referred to](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287603/), we don't delete answers because they're wrong.

Comment: @JoshCaswell We don't delete someone else's answer because we think it's wrong.  If *everyone* knows that it's wrong, including the author, then deleting it is fine.  The problem is in deleting content whos correctness (or at least usefulness) is debatable, and also that mods are not experts in every topic area, and thus cannot judge the correctness/usefulness of answers in order to delete them for being wrong.  (There are also way too many wrong answers for mods to have the time to delete them all.)

Comment: if I should fix my answer if there is a flaw, why shouldn't I fix *other answers*?

Comment: @Ooker Because that's not what edits are for.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of answers *without changing their content*.  If there are other answers that you think are bad then rather than re-writing those answers you should post your own.  You can vote and comment on those answers so that others can understand that they're problematic and why.

Comment: I see. If then, why shouldn't the OP just write another correct answer (and downvote their old own themself)?

Comment: @Ooker Why *should* they?  If they know that the answer isn't useful then they should either fix it or remove it.  If you think someone else's answer is  bad answer *you can just be wrong*.  People can disagree over what a good answer is, or how a problem should be solved.  If you think someone else's answer is bad, *they* may think it's good.  If they know their own answer is bad, then it should just be gone.  We don't want questions just collecting lots of bad answers, we just don't want to delete/re-write answers that may be good just because one person disagrees with it.

Comment: Ok i get it. I think you should add what you just said in your answer. It's informative